# Multiply dataframe's row non-NA values "element-wise" with list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Imagine we have pandas.DataFrame like :

|  na |  na |  3  |  3  |  5  | 2. |
|  na |  5..  |  2  |  2  |  1  | na|
|  1..  |  2..  |  2  |  3  |na| na|

Idea is to multiply each row by const list like = [ 0, 1, 2, 3]
If we have na in a column then it should still be na in a results:

|  na |  na |  0  |  3  |  10  | 6  |
|  na |  0  |  2  |  4  |  3  | na |
|  0  |  2  |  4  |  9  |  na | na |

Comment: Shouldn't you have `0, 2, 4, 9` in the last row?

Answer (score 1):

Using `cumsum` and `mul` for variable number of `NaN`s and avoiding stack:

```
df.mul(df.notnull().cumsum(1).sub(1))
```

```
     0    1  2  3     4    5
0  NaN  NaN  0  3  10.0  6.0
1  NaN  0.0  2  4   3.0  NaN
2  0.0  2.0  4  9   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I assumed that `[0,1,2,3]` is just representatives of the actual constants, not really the order. It's good approach though.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks! Yea, I thought that `1, 2, 3` could vary with number of NaNs (for example, one row could be multiplied by `1,2,3,4,5` and some other by only `1,2`)

Comment: no, it's the constant list with N elements. Also, should mention that in each row of dataframe there are N notna elements.

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов Interesting! But this solution should still work. Just notice that `na` is a string and not a `NaN`. If you have `na` in your data frame, please use `df.replace('na', np.nan)` first before trying this solution

Comment: @rafaels so this solution works with 6 columns dataframe as well as with (for instance) 60 columns dataframe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203606/discussion-between---and-rafaelc).

Comment: @rafaels a little bit confused how my list of constants used in your solution?
because it can be not like 1,2,3,4 , but random constants like 0,12,33,11,8 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can stack then unstack:

```
df.stack().mul(np.tile(const, df.shape[0])).unstack()
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3     4    5
0  NaN  NaN  0.0  3.0  10.0  6.0
1  NaN  0.0  2.0  4.0   3.0  NaN
2  0.0  2.0  4.0  9.0   NaN  NaN
```